# making a public user profile with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Devise doesn't have a user profile page, so I'm rolling my own. What I've figured out so far is this:

Controller:

```
class Users::ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
as :user do
  get 'users/profile/:username', to: 'users/profiles#show'
end
resources :users, :only =>[:show]
```

View:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= current_user.username %>
<% else %>
    <%= User.find_by(username: params[:username]) %>
<% end %>
```

The problem here is this just renders something like `#<User:0x007fa986d711d0>`, which changes every time I load the page.

Comment: Why are you finding the `User` in the view? `User.find_by(username: params[:username])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `show` method you are already finding your `User` by the `username`.

You could change your `else` statement to an attribute that you are looking for like:

```
@user.username or User.find_by(username: params[:username]).username
```

When you use `User.find_by(username: params[:username])` it finds the `User` object by the `username` parameter and returns the object since no attributes are being displayed.

Also it could be helpful to move your View logic out and instead use a Helper or use [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper).